# how to use wget to clone a website directory and subdirectories only

Tags: python, wget

I usually use wget to clone websites but in this case am trying to clone a specific directory only

I get only the index.html cloned this is the code `wget --limit-rate=700k --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off -U mozilla https://www.offsec.com/metasploit-unleashed/`  on kali. Am supposed to get the directory /metasploit-unleashed/ for offline preview.Is there something am missing or is there a python code I can implement to get this done?

Comment: *get only the index.html* please inspect said file using text editor and write what is inside. Does it looks like valid html document? Does it contain some links (`<a>` tags with set `href`s)?

Comment: Yeah I got a zipped file with this file only - file:///home/phan/.cache/.fr-xgTAyQ/index.html  other links and sub directories where not included

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question and explain the situation you encountered in detail.
If I understand correctly, you should want Python to automatically crawl the content on this page and save it in the local metasploit specified directory.
You can try to use the requests module, such as:

```py
import reqeusts

url = 'https://www.offsec.com/metasploit-unleashed/'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0"
}

res = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text

filePath = '...' # This is the path you want to store

with open(filePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(res)
```

Comment: No. Am trying to download the website directory  offsec.com/metasploit-unleashed/ from offsec.com. Instead of downloading the entire website but am having problem getting it done. I can only get the index.html of /metasploit-unleashed/ directory. I also tried the code you shared above I get this error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reqeusts'` I think the error is caused by something else. Please can you try the code if it works?

Comment: @Freeman This error is because you did not install this module. Please use `python - m pip install requests` (where "python" is python in your environment variable) to install it. Execute the code again.

Comment: When I use pip install I get this `pip install requests
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (3.3)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (1.26.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2022.9.24)
`

Comment: I think the error is not from requests. I mean I used `import requests
print (requests)` and I got `runfile('/home/phan/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='/home/phan/.config/spyder-py3')
<module 'requests' from '/home/phan/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>` on the spyder ide.

Comment: I think the problem is from line 8 of this code `import reqeusts

url = 'https://www.offsec.com/metasploit-unleashed/'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0"
}

res = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text

filePath = '/home/phan/' # This is the path you want to store

with open(filePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(res)` this line exactly `res = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text` but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Freeman Please show me the complete error reporting information.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reqeusts'` this is just the complete error printed on my ide. Since I don't fully understand how python process things unlike php I think maybe the error is from either installation problem, path (I used pip install and the one you shared above) or the ide am using. Just can't get my head around it. Is there a way I can troubleshoot the problem? I think the code is okay but my computer is the problem perhaps something with the python installation. The only error is just this single line `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reqeusts'`

Comment: `runfile('/home/phantom/pyextract.py', wdir='/home/phantom')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/pyextract.py:1
    import reqeusts

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reqeusts'` please help

Comment: my both computers have same errors. Don't understand what you mean by "where python is python in your environment variables" as stated above. Please I need help I had to go and purchase a new computer installed kali and am still getting same error from spyder and on my terminal when I run the script.

Comment: Are you using `python` or `python3`? Regardless, please enter this `python - m pip install requests` in the shell before executing the code.<br>Because your Python does not have the requests library installed.

Comment: I still get this error on my terminal `└─$ python - m pip install requests
Python 3.11.2 (main, Feb 12 2023, 00:48:52) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1

`

Comment: `/home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> run /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    run /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /home/phantom-of-africa/.config/spyder-py3/extract.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>`

Comment: After you enter this "python -m pip install requests", does a prompt like this appear?
`Requirement already satisfied: requests in h:\python3.7\lib\site-packages (2.28.2)`, If not, it means that you have not installed this module correctly.

Comment: Note that there are no symbols (including spaces) between "-m"

Comment: Yes it does display requirement already satisfied. But am buying a new pc for windows 11 once it arrives, I'll have to try it from a windows computer. Hopefully It would work.

Comment: I've seen where the error is coming from. I wonder how it took me long. On the request line, `requests` is missed spelt as `reqeusts` that's the error now works on the three computers Lol. Anyway am running into this error `IsADirectoryError: [Errn0 21] Is a directory: '/home/phan/'` on kali and `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:'` On the windows computer I notice it's two different error codes.